# How do I layer background pictures by expanding empty tags?

Tags: html, css, size

I want to layer background images so I can get a nice effect with borders.

I think my code is simple enough, but the problem I am having is that the tags don't want to expand correctly. I'll explain more later. Here's the html:

```
    <!doctype html>

    <html>
        <head>


        <title>My blog</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webdev.css"/>  
        </head>

        <body class='body'>
            <div class='outer'>
                <div class='inner'>
</div>
            </div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

The stylesheet:

```
  .body
{
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    display: block;
}

.outer
{
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    display: block;
}

.inner
{
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

I am not 100% sure the clearfixes are necessary yet. Basically I want the divs to all encapsulate the entire screen no matter what the screen size. Thanks for any and all responses. If I'm not clear feel free to comment and I will explain more, but I think the question is fairly basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
body
{
    height:100%;
}

.outer
{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}

.inner
{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the width 100% is as simple as setting "width: 100%", the height is a bit harder..

You need to have "height: 100%" on both the `<html>` and `<body>`-tag.
And then "height: auto; height: 100%; min-height: 100%;" on your `<div>`'s

The reason that you have two "height" is because IE6 don't understand the "height: auto" and then needs the "height: 100%" instead.

You can see an example of this here: http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/full-height-updated.html